# Summation of amplitudes

Tags: circuit-construction, superposition

I was wondering how to create generalized entangled superpositions of qubits when I came to need of an algorithm to generate the following:

Suppose we have two $n$ qubit states, $$|\psi\rangle = \sum_X \alpha_X\ |X\rangle$$
and, $$|\phi\rangle = \sum_X \beta_X\ |X\rangle.$$

How do I come up with a state, $$|\psi'\rangle = \frac1{\sqrt N}\sum_X (\alpha_X+\beta_X)\ |X\rangle,$$
where $N$ is the normalization factor?

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.04349 Section II

Comment: @Hemant thanks a lot! I'll check it out.

Comment: See this question https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/5929/how-to-superpose-two-composite-qubit-states